# why pull to refresh is not refreshing my list using flutter

Tags: flutter, refresh

here I am using the pull_to_refresh package. and I am calling the HomeSlider widget and HomeContect widget. and these two widgets are taking values from firebase. the pull_to_refresh widget is appearing, but it is not refreshing values from firebase.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  RefreshController _refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
  void _onRefresh() async {
    // monitor network fetch
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // if failed,use refreshFailed()
    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [

      SmartRefresher(
        controller: _refreshController,
        onRefresh: _onRefresh,
        enablePullDown: true,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 180, child: HomeSlider()),
            HomeContents(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your onRefresh method, you should be calling the firebase method to re-fetch your values from firebase. However, you don't seem to be calling any other method in your onRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

In the _onRefresh() method you should call your method to fetch data, then use setState to make it visible on the screen.